# Position an element at the bottom of a floating div with unknown height

Tags: javascript, html, css, positioning, vertical-alignment

I am currently trying to position an element in a way that it always is at the bottom of it's parent. What's special here is that none of the heights or widths are known. I'd like to do this without tables, if at all possible (my superior is against using those. In a very religious way).

I tried the approach of using `position:relative` on the parent and `position:absolute; bottom:0;` on the box I want to have at the bottom. This, however, causes the box to overlap with the other content of the parent div since absolute positioning causes the parent to ignore the height of the positioned element. Some JavaScript is used to align the heights of the floating divs to each other. But disabled JavaScript should not completely break the layout (as in: cause content to overlap or break the "flow" of the page).

Here's the fiddle with the exact structure of my markup: http://jsfiddle.net/vbeC2/27/

I did read the "float: bottom" question on SO, but none of the answers really adressed my problem, hence the new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the cleanest solution, but since you were already using the maxHeight bit to calculate the sizes, I just added a second each loop to check the max-height of the bottom section, and added it, so that the `relative, absolute positioning` would work.

http://jsfiddle.net/robsterlini/svcGB/ or http://codepen.io/robsterlini/pen/BcDyt

**EDIT** When you resize your browser it won't work, but you could just add a resize event that recalculated it, and you'd need to think about creating some javascript-less fallbacks, either using modernizr, or just some simple

Comment: So in the end, this cannot be acomplished without javascript?

Comment: not to my knowledge, but that's not the end of the world. The majority of people have it on, and if it's carefully coded it can be lightweight, and very useful. Just make sure that you have some sort of noscript fall back and you'll be just fine!

Answer (score 1):

Please find the working demo here: [JS Enabled](http://jsfiddle.net/vbeC2/53/)

Modified the jquery logic to calculate the height of the maximum height of the container as shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Set the height of the columns to the highest value of all columns
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $(".same-height").each(function(){
        var k = $(this).children('.headline').innerHeight() + $(this).children('.description').innerHeight()+$(this).children('.bottom').innerHeight();
        maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight,k);
    });

    $(".same-height").css({"height" : maxHeight});
});
```

If JavaScript is disabled then you should apply different styles as shown in demo here: 
[JS Disabled](http://jsfiddle.net/vbeC2/65/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is something similar to what you want to atchive but the demo is centering the

http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

You should use the same trick : using css ::after/::before pseudo classes to set your footer content in your parent div

Comment: I have tried adapting that solution, but it seems to break the layout: http://jsfiddle.net/vbeC2/52/ I also have no idea why this would work (even in the case of wanting to vertically center a box). Did I do something wrong?